# How to plot in % the difference b/w output and input signal in AC analysis [LTspice]

Tags: ltspice, bode-plot

I tried the plot `mag(((re(V(vout))-re(V(vin)))/re(V(vout))))*100`, but this leads to unexpected results.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? If you want the transfer function of your circuit, tell us that, for example.

Answer (score 0):

write 100*(mag(v(out))/mag(v(in)))-1).

If you have the input voltage =1 in the ac analysis, write 100*(mag(v(out))-1)

Your own equation wipes off the imagininary part. That can be a substantial error.